# Why use an escape sequence instead of a different quote type?

Tags: python

Why would we want to use escape sequence characters like for example in this Python code:

```py
print('It\'s alright.')
```

Why are we using this backslash to print a single quote when we can accomplish the same by using:

```py
print("it's alright")
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with the `print` function. `txt = "It's alright"` works as well, but how is Python supposed to know that in `'It's alright'` the string ends at the third rather than second quote mark? This is just how Python string literals work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter how many different kinds of quote you have, you may still need an escape mechanism now and then. Consider this:

> If you want to use Python's "multiline string literal" you have to begin it and end it with a triple quote, which can be either `"""` or `'''`.

To put that into a string literal you are going to have to quote `'` or `"`:

```
a = 'If you want to use Python\'s "multiline string literal" you have to begin it and end it with a triple quote, which can be either """ or \'\'\'.'.
a = "If you want to use Python's \"multiline string literal\" you have to begin it and end it with a triple quote, which can be either \"\"\" or '''."
a = """If you want to use Python's "multiline string literal" you have to begin it and end it with a triple quote, which can be either ""\" or '''."""
```

Having different quote types is a great programming convenience, making it easier and less error prone to put quotes and apostrophes in the data without having to jump through hoops. But it can't cover every case. If you need to convince yourself of this, experiment with those three lines at a command prompt and see if you can come up with a way to avoid backslashes. You will find you always need at least one.

Answer (score 2):

This is useful because you can do:

```
txt = 'in python you can have \'string\' or "string"'
print(txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code

```
txt = 'It\'s alright.'
```

you need the backslash(\) so python understands that the second apostrophe is a character of the string. Without the backslash, Python would interpret it as the character used to mark the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Without further context, I can only take a guess and say that the person who wrote the first example, didn't know or wasn't aware of the fact that it's possible to use double-quotes `""` for string literals in Python.

Answer (score 0):

That's just a matter of style. Some people like to use single quotes to create string literals, and therefore they'll have to escape any single quotes it comes inside of their strings (same for double quotes). The following will raise a SyntaxError:

```
s = 'It's gonna be alright!'
s = "They used to call me "Big" but I was 4ft!"
```

So you may ask why they don't use `"` when their string have single quotes and `'` when their string have double quotes? Yes, they can, but there are some unavoidable situations, such as Regex:

```
regexp = r"["']\w+["']"
```

Note that they can't use neither single nor double quotes to create the string, since both are present in the Regex. Therefore, they'll need to escape it.

Comment: "They used to call me "Big" but I was 4ft!". Love this!

Answer (score 0):

In this case its not needed cuz you have used " " for the print statement.

case1) use: `print(" It's alright.")`

case2) use: `print(' It\'s alright.')`

Note the parenthesis used for the print statements.
You cant use `'` directly in **case2** cuz python would think that the string ends causing a `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a `'` at the start, python looks for a matching `'` and considers whatever is present in between these quotes as a string.

But if you use a `'` in the middle of the string, python considers that as the end of the string. And since there is no matching `'` for the `'` at the end of the string that results in a `SyntaxError`

*The backslash () character is used to escape characters that otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline, backslash itself, or the quote character.*

Refer the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals